# How can I remove characters after underscore?

Tags: python, string, file

I need to convert a text like

> photo_id 102297_skdjksd223238 text  black dog in a water

to

> photo_id 102297 text  black dog in a water

by removeing the substring after underscore

```
inputFile = open("text.txt", "r") 
exportFile = open("result", "w")
sub_str = "_"
for line in inputFile:    
   new_line = line[:line.index(sub_str) + len(sub_str)]
   exportFile.writelines(new_line)
```

but couldn't access the second underscore as it removed all text after photo_id ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the first underscore from the right:

```
s= "photo_id 102297_skdjksd223238 text black dog in a water"
prefix, suffix = s.rsplit('_', 1)
print(f"{prefix} {suffix.split(' ', 1)[-1]}")
```

Out:

```
photo_id 102297 text black dog in a water
```

Comment: since `maxsplit=1` just use `rpartition` and `partition`

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note: The question was tagged [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) when I wrote this:</sup>

```
_[^\s]*
```

- `_` - a literal `_`
- `[^\s]*` - (or `\S*` if supported) any character but whitespaces - zero or more times

Substitute with a blank string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lepjcU/1)

```py
inp = 'photo_id 102297_skdjksd223238 text black dog in a water foo_baz bar'

res = re.sub(r'_[^\s]*', '', inp)

print(res)
```

Output

```
photo 102297 text black dog in a water foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a pattern to capture the leading digits to make it a bit more specific, and then match the underscore followed by optional non whitespace characters.

In the replacement use the first capture group.

```
\b(\d+)_\S*
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(\d+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits
- `_\S*` Match an underscore and optional non whitespace characters

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eqp1DU/1).

```
import re
 
pattern = r"\b(\d+)_\S*"
s = "photo_id 102297_skdjksd223238 text black dog in a water"
 
result = re.sub(pattern, r"\1", s)
 
if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
photo_id 102297 text black dog in a water
```

---

Another option including `photo_id` and matching until the first underscore:

```
\b(photo_id\s+[^_\s]+)_\S*
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/1srWGf/1).